# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: add_reaction() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Basically, I'm trying to create a poll/vote command that allows you to add the reactions ":thumbsup:" for agree and ":thumbsdown:" for disagree. For example:

`User: Am I male?`

`Reactions: :thumbsup:, :thumbsdown:`

`Meaning of Reactions: [yes:no]`

This is my full code:

```
@client.command()
async def poll(ctx, *, message):
    await ctx.send(f"{message}")
    await Message.add_reaction(emoji=u"\U0001F44D")
```

Whenever I call the command, the message is sent but the reaction is not added. This error pops up instead

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: add_reaction() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

The full error is here:

```
Ignoring exception in on_command_error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\danie\Documents\Scripts\Bots\DiscordBot\skybot.py", line 53, in poll
    await discord.Message.add_reaction(emoji=u"\U0001F44D")
TypeError: add_reaction() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\danie\Documents\Scripts\Bots\DiscordBot\skybot.py", line 189, in on_command_error
    raise error
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: add_reaction() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
Ignoring exception in on_command_error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\danie\Documents\Scripts\Bots\DiscordBot\skybot.py", line 53, in poll
    await discord.Message.add_reaction(emoji=u"\U0001F44D")
TypeError: add_reaction() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\danie\Documents\Scripts\Bots\DiscordBot\skybot.py", line 189, in on_command_error
    raise error
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: add_reaction() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

This is my source for the emoji [unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f44d/index.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discord.py `send()` function returns a Message, so all you should have to do is set your send function to a variable.

```
@client.command()
async def poll(ctx, *, message):
    message = await ctx.send(message)
    await message.add_reaction(u"\U0001F44D")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need an instance of a message not a class, store your message in a variable. In this case the variable is `msg`:

```
@client.command()
async def poll(ctx, *, message):
    msg = await ctx.send(f"{message}")
    await msg.add_reaction(emoji=u"\U0001F44D")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really appreciate it. I accepted the other guy since he had a lower reputation. Hope you understand. :)

Comment: No problem, glad you found your answer!